# Extract surname with initial in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I have a column `NAME` with data like this:

```
1, CHAN Tai Man
2, CHAN Ting Ting
```

I would like to have a query that extract the `NAME2` to

```
1, CHAN T M
2, CHAN T T
```

As you may observe that only initial of the given name is required. How can I achieve that in SQL Server 2008? Many thanks for your gentle help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gordon said,the first one is easy and here's my take on it

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(id INT,name nvarchar(50))
Insert into @table
Values(1,'CHAN Tai Man')
Insert into @table
Values(2, 'CHAN Ting Ting')
select name
 , LEFT(name, (PATINDEX('%[ _-]%',name))) +substring(name,(PATINDEX('%[ _-]%',name)+1),1) +' '+substring(reverse(rtrim(substring(reverse(name), 1, charindex(' ', reverse(name))))),(PATINDEX('%[ _-]%',reverse(rtrim(substring(reverse(name), 1, charindex(' ', reverse(name))))))+1),1) as Fullname     
from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

The first initial is pretty easy:

```
select left(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1)
```

The second is a bit tougher.  I think the logic is like this

```
select (left(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1) +
        substring(reverse(name), charindex(' ', reverse(name)) - 1, 1)
       )
```

You might need to include `case` statements to be sure that the name has two spaces.